# Adding image and text fields to Quicksight Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

My customer wishes at least logo on their dashboard, but I can't find any way to add images to QuickSight Dashboard.

Is it really not possible to add images (or additional text fields to explain some details) to QuickSight dashboards?

Answer (score 5):

In March 2020 AWS has added the possibility to insert images to the dashboards using narratives:

- Click **+Add** and choose **Add insight**.
- Click on the chevron on the top right corner of the visual and then **Customize narrative**.
- Click on the image icon in the editor and enter your image URL.

Narratives are also useful for providing any text content to the user.

Link to AWS Quicksight documentation: [Working with the Expression Editor Screen and Menus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/using-narratives-expression-editor-menus.html)

**EDIT 20/10/2021**

In June 2021 Quicksight added a new chart type: custom visual content that makes embedding images even simpler:

- Add new visual of type custom visual content
- Click **Customize visual**
- Paste the URL and tick **Show as image** checkbox

Learn more: [Using Custom Visual Content in Amazon QuickSight](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/custom-visual-content.html)

Answer (score 1):

Updated even further in late June 2021 with the new Custom Visual Content Control see the AWS link - [Using Custom Visual Content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/custom-visual-content.html). This lets you add both images and links to content on other websites.

Comment: Is it possible to show images in each generated report row instead of HTTPS URLs? Like user signatures?

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid, it is so in QuickSight. It was launched in 2016, there is a long way to go before it can do everything that Tableau can.